# Discord.py "self is a required argument that is missing"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I continue to get this error when I use a specific command with Discord.py to make my bot:

```
    raise MissingRequiredArgument('{0.name} is a required argument that is missing.'.format(param))
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: self is a required argument that is missing.
```

My current code is:

```
@bot.command()
async def about(self):
        """Tells you information about the bot itself."""
        result = ['**About Me:**']
        result.append('- Author: AmusedGrape [ID: 401792058970603539]')
        result.append('- Library: discord.py (Python)')
        result.append('- Latest Change: 2.0 Update')
        result.append('- Uptime: {}'.format(get_bot_uptime()))
        result.append('- Servers: {}'.format(len(bot.servers)))
        result.append('- Commands Run: {}'.format(sum(bot.commands_used.values())))

        total_members = sum(len(s.members) for s in bot.servers)
        total_online  = sum(1 for m in bot.get_all_members() if m.status != discord.Status.offline)
        unique_members = set(bot.get_all_members())
        unique_online = sum(1 for m in unique_members if m.status != discord.Status.offline)
        channel_types = Counter(c.type for c in bot.get_all_channels())
        voice = channel_types[discord.ChannelType.voice]
        text = channel_types[discord.ChannelType.text]
        result.append('- Total Members: {} ({} online)'.format(total_members, total_online))
        result.append('- Unique Members: {} ({} online)'.format(len(unique_members), unique_online))
        result.append('- {} text channels, {} voice channels'.format(text, voice))
        result.append('')
        result.append('Tex server: https://discord.gg/~~~~~~')
        await bot.say('\n'.join(result))
```

I based the code off of this site: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/107401/discord.py
I am not a master at Python but I know a small amount.
Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Full traceback

```js
Ignoring exception in command about
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 367, in invoke
    yield from self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 345, in prepare
    yield from self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 304, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = yield from self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 212, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument('{0.name} is a required argument that is missing.'.format(param))
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: self is a required argument that is missing.
```

```js
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', description=description)
```

That is what "bot" is defined as. I am using discord.ext.

Comment: @abccd Just updated the post

Comment: (My mistake in the previous comment, I misread the exception) But is the command in a class? If it is, can you post the general structure of your entire code please (not your full code, but the class `about` is in, what you're doing with that class, how you're handling that class, and how you're using `bot`)

Comment: @abccd Post updated.

Comment: no not that, where location wise is `async def about(self):`, is it under a class? If so, what are you doing with the class.

Comment: @abccd it is not

Comment: Then you don't need the `self`, `async def about():`

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def about(ctx):
        """Tells you information about the bot itself."""
        result = ['**About Me:**']
        result.append('- Author: AmusedGrape [ID: 401792058970603539]')
        result.append('- Library: discord.py (Python)')
        result.append('- Latest Change: 2.0 Update')
        result.append('- Uptime: {}'.format(get_bot_uptime()))
        result.append('- Servers: {}'.format(len(bot.servers)))
        result.append('- Commands Run: {}'.format(sum(bot.commands_used.values())))

        total_members = sum(len(s.members) for s in bot.servers)
        total_online  = sum(1 for m in bot.get_all_members() if m.status != discord.Status.offline)
        unique_members = set(bot.get_all_members())
        unique_online = sum(1 for m in unique_members if m.status != discord.Status.offline)
        channel_types = Counter(c.type for c in bot.get_all_channels())
        voice = channel_types[discord.ChannelType.voice]
        text = channel_types[discord.ChannelType.text]
        result.append('- Total Members: {} ({} online)'.format(total_members, total_online))
        result.append('- Unique Members: {} ({} online)'.format(len(unique_members), unique_online))
        result.append('- {} text channels, {} voice channels'.format(text, voice))
        result.append('')
        result.append('Tex server: https://discord.gg/~~~~~~')
        await ctx.send('\n'.join(result))
```

After the rewrite, for your bot to send anything, you must use context(ctx). That's why we include that argument in the function. For the bot to send the message, we use `ctx.send("Your text here")`. The text can also be replaced by a variable.

Comment: Always include a textual desc on what you've changed. It really helps